# how to fill combobox hidden in webbrowser using VB.NET

Tags: javascript, vb.net

I can fill the second `combobox`, but I can not fill the third combobox, anyone can help?
my code:

```
WebBrowser1.Navigate ("http://lazindo.com/bri/")
```

for the second combo:

`WebBrowser1.Document.Window.Document.GetElementById("PAYEE_CODE").SetAttribute ("value","1,25000|50000|75000|100000|150000|200000|300000")`

for the third combo:

```
WebBrowser1.Document.Window.Document.GetElementById ("NOMINAL"). SetAttribute ("value", "25000")
```

This does not work, Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can do that? VB's WebBrowser has those functions? I thought you would need to do `Navigate("javascript:..")`. Anyway, what exactly is the problem (as in, what does the console return)?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're getting the element with the ID of "PAYEE_CODE," which is a `<select>` not the `<option>` object that's below it that you want to change. And then I have no idea what "FACE" is, I don't see it anywhere in the document.

Comment: sorry, not "FACE" but "NOMINAL", maybe you can give an example? I would be very grateful

Comment: please anyone who can give me a sample code for this problem